# Конструкция FOR IN LOOP в функции PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Переношу код функции из пакета в sql на c#. Немного не могу понять кусок кода, а именно:

```
FOR rec
               IN (  SELECT v1.pipe_number,
                            v1.workplace_id,
                            v1.next_direction,
                            v1.instruction_type,
                            v1.not_zakaz_reason_id
                       FROM    tesc3.v_inspection_pipes v1
                            LEFT JOIN
                               tesc3.v_inspection_pipes v2
                            ON     v1.pipe_number = v2.pipe_number
                               AND v2.edit_state = 0
                               AND v2.next_direction = 'SKLAD'
                               AND (v2.instruction_type =
                                       'РАСПОРЯЖЕНИЕ'
                                    OR v2.not_zakaz_reason_id IS NOT NULL)
                               AND v2.trx_date >= startdate
                               AND v2.trx_date < enddate
                      WHERE     v1.edit_state = 0
                            AND v1.next_direction IS NOT NULL
                            AND v2.pipe_number IS NOT NULL
                   ORDER BY v1.pipe_number, v1.trx_date DESC)
            LOOP
               -- если новая труба, сбрасываем счетчик записей по трубе
               IF (last_pipe != rec.pipe_number)
               THEN
                  num_rec := 0;
               END IF;

           -- если последняя запись не являетмя переводом, говорим, что нужно перейти к следующей трубе
           IF (rec.instruction_type != 'РАСПОРЯЖЕНИЕ'
               AND rec.not_zakaz_reason_id IS NULL)
           THEN
              num_rec := 100;
           END IF;

           -- если последняя запись сделана с линии, плюсуем и даем знать, что нужно переходить к след трубе
           IF (num_rec = 0 AND rec.workplace_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
           THEN
              BEGIN
                 loss_value := loss_value + 1;
                 num_rec := 100;
              END;
           END IF;

           -- если предпоследняя запись сделана с линии и отправлено на ремонт или склад, плюсуем и даем знать, что нужно переходить к след трубе
           IF (num_rec = 1 AND rec.workplace_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
               AND (rec.next_direction = 'REMONT'
                    OR rec.next_direction = 'SKLAD'))
           THEN
              BEGIN
                 loss_value := loss_value + 1;
                 num_rec := 100;
              END;
           END IF;

           last_pipe := rec.pipe_number;
           num_rec := num_rec + 1;
        END LOOP;
```

В части in запрос возвращающий выборку строк и столбцов. Но насколько я понял читая про for loop в in должно попадать начальное и конечное значение счётчика. В моём случае rec. Или я что то не понимаю? И ещё не понятно что означает например `rec.pipe_number`.

Comment: не понял, вы про какой счетчик ? rec это неявный курсор, т.е. структура, содержащая одну текущую запись из выборки. и rec.pipe_number обращение к полю в этой структуре. т.е. к полю pipe_number из текущей строки выборки

Comment: @Mike, понял. А что тогда является счётчиком для этого цикла? И сколько раз он будет пробегать от чего зависит в данном случае? Пока не пробежит все записи из курсора я так понимаю?

Comment: да, пока записи не закончатся и счетчика тут нет

Comment: Ну тогда всё понял. И понял как это перетащить на c#. Большое спасибо @Mike!

Comment: @Mike Ваши комментарии вполне можно оформить как ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Основные отличия цикла с явным (*explicit*) и неявным (*implicit*) курсорами
хорошо видны на примере ниже. Неявный курсор не имеет, в отличии от явного, переменной курсора, и соответственно для него недоступны атрибуты курсора - `rowcount`, `notfound`, `found`.

В обоих случаях, `FOR-LOOP` неявно открывает и закрывает курсор. Также неявно создаётся переменнвя (в примере `r` типа `ROWTYPE`), которая обновляется при каждой итерации цикла и содержит текущую запись из выборки. Область видимости этой переменной, только тело цикла. Для явного курсора можно просто объявить совместимую переменную (`myrow`), а для неявного надо сначало создавать новый тип записи с повторным перечислением всех полей выборки.

```
declare 
    cursor c is select 1 id, 'item' item from dual;
    myrow c%rowtype;
    rowcount integer := 0;
    procedure handleRow (myrow c%rowtype) is begin null; /* do something */ end;
begin
    <<explicit>> for r in c loop 
        dbms_output.put_line('row['||c%rowcount||'] '||r.id||'|'||r.item);
        handleRow (r);
    end loop;

    <<implicit>> for r in (select 1 id, 'item' item from dual) loop 
        rowcount := rowcount + 1;
        dbms_output.put_line('row['||rowcount||'] '||r.id||'|'||r.item); 
    end loop;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

row[1] 1|item
row[1] 1|item
```