# Ошибка при создании процедуры: [Encountered the symbol "END"]

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqldeveloper

Есть 3 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."ID_DOWNLOADS" 
(   "LOADID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DATELOAD" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    CONSTRAINT "ID_DOWNLOADS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("LOADID")
);

CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."CAR_BRAND" 
(   "CARBRANDID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BRANDNAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    CONSTRAINT "CAR_BRAND_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CARBRANDID")
);

CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."SALECAR" 
(   "CARBRANDID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CARMODELID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COST" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SALEDATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LOADID" NUMBER
```

);

Нужно написать процедуру, в которою подается дата. По этой дате нужно с первой таблицы взять `loadid` и присвоить переменной. Потом по значению этой переменной вывести таблицу в которой будет `BRANDNAME` и сумма `COST` по этому бренду.

Я написал следующие

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure SummSale ( date_in IN date ) IS
    no_loadid1 EXCEPTION;
    Loadid1 number;
    TYPE SummSale IS RECORD (
      Brandname   VARCHAR2(30),
      Cost1  NUMBER (20)
    );
    summ_sale SummSale;
begin
    SELECT loadid INTO loadid1 from id_downloads where dateload = date_in;
    IF loadid1 = NULL THEN
       RAISE no_loadid1;
    ELSE
      SELECT Br.BRANDNAME, SUM(Sc.COSTT) AS COSTT INTO Summ_Sale.Brandname, 
      Summ_Sale.Costt 
      FROM CAR_BRAND Br INNER JOIN SALECAR Sc ON Br.CARBRANDID = 
      Sc.CARBRANDID
       WHERE (((loadid1) = Sc.loadid)) GROUP BY Br.BRANDNAME;  
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Brandname:   ' || Summ_Sale.Brandname);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cost:   ' || Summ_Sale.Cost1);  
    END if;
exception
    WHEN no_loadid1 THEN
    raise_application_error (-20001,'load id not found in order to submit.');
    end;
END SummSale;
/
show errors
declare
  date1 date;
begin
  date1:=28/01/2018;
  SummSale(date1); 
end;
/
```

Вопрос в следующем. Адекватно ли написан `select` после `else` и почему  ругается:

> Encountered the symbol "END"

в конце процедуры?

Comment: "Адекватно ли написан select" - нет.  `select ... into ... from`.  Или используйте курсоры, `bulk collect into`. Описание таблиц не полное,  добавте `create table ...`. Исключение `no_loadid1` не нужно.

Comment: У вас в процедуре лишний `end`, вот оно и ругается. Форматируйте код, и такие проблемы сразу будут видны.

Comment: @0xdb С временной таблице не много понять не могу, ее описать надо, она будет состоять из 2 полей, похожей по структуре таблицы нет. Получается ее только создать можно и уже туда записывать?

Comment: А где у вас "временной таблице" в вопросе? Или что вы имете ввиду?

Comment: @0xdb SELECT ... INTO SummSaleTable. SummSaleTable временная  таблица насколько я понял и описывается она SummSaleTable Название_Существующей_Таблицы%ROWTYPE.

Comment: Aaa, переменная типа записи, тогда да. Надо объявить record с двумя полями, потом переменную. Или используйте [неявный курсор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729351/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-for-in-loop-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-plsql/729671#729671).

Comment: @0xdb Спасибо за помощь, теперь явных ошибок нет и оно компилируется. Только при выводе ничего нет.

Comment: Не забудте включить вывод - `set serveroutput on size unlimited`

Comment: @0xdb не помогает, видимо сам sql пустой возвращается

Comment: Совет: начните  сначала - две строчки кода, проверте, далее следующую порцию кода и т.д. Запросы проверяйте отдельно, быстрее найдёте, что по условию `ON Br.CARBRANDID = Sc.CARMODELID` что-то вернётся.

Comment: @0xdb да бред уже какой то, что то в коде меняешь он начинает на 4 строку ругаться, ctrl x + ctrl v и компилируется, убрал всю процедуру, все равно на 4 строку ругается. Бред.

Comment: А что в 4-й строке? `date1:=28/01/2018;` - ну да, бред, замените на - `date1:=date'2018-01-28';`.

Comment: @0xdb, да, я время не дату не правильно передавал. Не понимаю как тут компилятор работает, исправил. 1 раз вывод прошел, при повтором запуске not a GROUP BY expression в 15. (И нумерация скачет. То от начала главного блока, то от начала процедуры считает)

Comment: Ешё раз обратите внимание на совет несколько комментариев выше. Почему вы не хотите ему следовать?

Comment: @0xdb все работает, осталось только запрос дописать что бы он по id сумму складывал, а то там по where 1 запись остается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С учётом поправленного запроса в связанном [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822381/single-row-subquery-returns-more-than-one-row?noredirect=1&lq=1) и обсуждений в комментариях, рабочий вариант процедуры следующий:

```
create or replace procedure printSumSale (dateLoad date) is
    loadId number;
    cursor getSumCostPerBrand (loadId number) is
        SELECT br.BrandName, SUM(sc.cost) Costs
        FROM car_brand br 
        INNER JOIN salecar sc ON br.carBrandId = sc.carBrandId
        WHERE sc.loadId = getSumCostPerBrand.loadId
        GROUP BY br.BrandName
        ;
    sumCostPerBrand getSumCostPerBrand%rowtype;
    function getLoadId (dateLoad date) return number is
        ret number;
        found boolean := false; 
    begin
        for r in (
            SELECT loadid 
            FROM id_downloads 
            WHERE dateLoad = getLoadId.dateLoad) loop
            if not found then 
                ret := r.loadId; 
                found := true;
            else raise_application_error (
                -20001, 'fatal: dateLoad='||dateLoad||' more then one rows found ('||ret||','||r.loadId||')'); 
            end if;
        end loop;
        if found then     
            return ret;
        else raise_application_error (
            -20002, 'fatal: loadId='||loadId||' does not exist yet'); 
        end if;
    end getLoadId;
begin
    loadId := getLoadId (dateLoad);
    for r in getSumCostPerBrand (loadId) loop
        dbms_output.put_line ('Brandname: '||r.BrandName||' Costs: '||r.Costs);
    end loop;
exception when others then
    dbms_output.put_line (sqlerrm||chr(10)||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace());
    raise;
end printSumSale;
/
declare
    loadDate date := date'2018-01-28';
begin
    printSumSale (loadDate); 
end;
/
```