# Single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."SALECAR" 
   ("CARBRANDID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CARMODELID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COSTT" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SALEDATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LOADID" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_ID_DOWNLOADS" FOREIGN KEY ("LOADID")
      REFERENCES "SYSTEM"."ID_DOWNLOADS" ("LOADID") ENABLE
   );                                                                      
 CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."CAR_BRAND" 
   (    "CARBRANDID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BRANDNAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "CAR_BRAND_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CARBRANDID")                
  );
```

Нужно написать запрос, есть переменная `loadid1` по которой нужно вывести таблицу в которой будет `BRANDNAME` и сумма `COST` по этому бренду.
Лучше этого придумать не могу.

```
SELECT Br.BRANDNAME, SUM(Sc.COSTT) AS COSTT
FROM CAR_BRAND Br INNER JOIN SALECAR Sc ON Br.CARBRANDID = Sc.CARBRANDID
WHERE Sc.CARBRANDID =
(SELECT Sc.Carbrandid FROM SALECAR WHERE loadid1 = Sc.loadid) 
GROUP BY Br.BRANDNAME;
```

SALE CARE
`1  10  989500  28.01.18    123
1   12  500000  29.01.18    NULL
1   11  4568    29.01.18    124
2   23  56464   27.01.18    125`
    CAR_BRAND
 `1 Ford
 2 Audi`

Comment: ошибка из за того, что подзапрос возвращает более одной записи. А сравнить одно значение с несколькими невозможно. Так же из текста вопроса и запроса не ясно что вы пытаетесь получить. По тексту вопроса выходит что вам просто нужна сумма в разрезе брендов, но в таком случае вам where в принципе не нужен. Видимо задача все таки другая, постарайтесь описать ее более ясно

Comment: @Mike нужна сумма в разрезе конкретного бренда, Sc.loadid которого совпадает со значением переменной полученной ранее

Comment: Что значит полученной ранее ? До начала выполнения этого запроса ? тогда просто where loadid=X. А если это получается в том же запросе на основе некой еще информации, надо понять на основе какой информации и по каким правилам он получается

Comment: @Mike ТС иммел ввиду "полученой ранее" как в предыдущем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822244/encountered-the-symbol-end), т.е. из предыдущего запроса в блоке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, `loadid1` - это некий идентификатор загрузки, а в пределах одной загрузки может быть несколько брендов? (По крейней мере, это объясняет, откуда такая ошибка). Тогда надо просто заменить `=` на `in`:

```
SELECT Br.BRANDNAME, SUM(Sc.COSTT) AS COSTT
FROM CAR_BRAND Br INNER JOIN SALECAR Sc ON Br.CARBRANDID = Sc.CARBRANDID
WHERE Sc.CARBRANDID in
(SELECT Sc.Carbrandid FROM SALECAR WHERE loadid1 = Sc.loadid) 
GROUP BY Br.BRANDNAME;
```

И кстати, а зачем вам вообще этот подзапрос? Вы уже приджойнили таблицу `SALECAR`, так что вот этот запрос должен возвращать те же самые данные:

```
SELECT Br.BRANDNAME, SUM(Sc.COSTT) AS COSTT
FROM CAR_BRAND Br INNER JOIN SALECAR Sc ON Br.CARBRANDID = Sc.CARBRANDID
WHERE Sc.loadid = loadid1
GROUP BY Br.BRANDNAME;
```

Comment: Просто по индефикатору загрузки надо выбрать id бренда, а уже по нему получить сумму продаж. Одному индефикатору загрузки соответствует один бренд. Спасибо за ответ, дома посмотрю.

Comment: Если одному индефикатору загрузки соответствует один бренд, то не должно бы такой ошибки быть... Заодно данные проверьте.

Comment: А тут проблема из за того что индефикатор может быть null. Поэтому на сколько я понимаю уникальным поле не сделать и отсюда уже следует все выше перечисленное

Comment: Проверил запросы, не работают. Сумму не считает, выводит по 1 полю.

Comment: Например Sc.Carbrandid = 1. Под запрос то же должен возвращать единицу. И у всех строк где Sc.Carbrandid = 1 должен складываться Sc.Costt. Почему берется только одна строка мне не понятно

Comment: А можете добавить в вопрос исходные данные, чтобы было, на чем проверить? Или создайте схему на sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: Добавил в конце вопроса

Comment: В подзапросе на FROM SALECAR SC исправить надо. Тогда работает