# Как в PL/SQL объявить временную переменную для хранения текущей строки курсора при условии, что строка у меня образуется из нескольких связных таблиц?

Tags: oracle, plsql, курсор

Имеется такой DML-код:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR salesinfo IS 
SELECT p.name, p.price, sp.dat, sn.name, d.dil_name
FROM products p, pricelist pl, salemap sp, saleman sn, dilers d
WHERE p.prod_id = pl.prod_id AND pl.dat = sp.dat AND sp.men_pers_code = 
sn.men_pers_code AND sn.n_dil = d.n_dil;
```

И тут проблема. Нужно объявить временную переменную для хранения текущей строки. Правильно ли я понимаю, что для того, чтобы реализовать эту временную переменную, мне необходимо написать подзапрос, выбирающий значения из этих таблиц?

Эта временная переменная имеет такой вид:

```
имя_переменной данные_для_переменной%ROWTYPE;
```

---

Вот что я пытался сделать:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR salesinfo IS
SELECT sn.name, d.dil_name, p.name, pl.price, sp.dat, (count(sn.men_pers_code) * sp.quantity)
FROM products p, pricelist pl, salemap sp, saleman sn, dilers d
WHERE p.prod_id = pl.prod_id AND pl.dat = sp.dat AND sp.men_pers_code = sn.men_pers_code AND sn.n_dil = d.n_dil
GROUP BY sn.name, d.dil_name, p.name, pl.price, sp.dat, sp.quantity
ORDER BY d.dil_name, (count(sn.men_pers_code) * sp.quantity) DESC;
info (SELECT sn.name, d.dil_name, p.name, pl.price, sp.dat, (count(sn.men_pers_code) * sp.quantity)
  FROM products p, pricelist pl, salemap sp, saleman sn, dilers d
  WHERE p.prod_id = pl.prod_id AND pl.dat = sp.dat AND sp.men_pers_code = sn.men_pers_code AND sn.n_dil = d.n_dil
  GROUP BY sn.name, d.dil_name, p.name, pl.price, sp.dat, sp.quantity)%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN salesinfo;
FETCH salesinfo INTO info;
WHILE salesinfo%FOUND LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (info.d.dil_name || chr(9) || info.sn.name || chr(9) || info.sp.dat || chr(9) || count(sn.men_pers_code * sp.quantity));
END LOOP;
CLOSE salesinfo;
```

В своём вопросе я имел в виду то, как мне описать переменную `info`, ведь в ней имеются данные из нескольких связанных таблиц.

Так вот, я сделал как показал выше и тут у меня вылезла такая ошибка в Oracle:

```
ORA-06550: line 8, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

constant exception <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table columns long
double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national
character nchar
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", line 592
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", line 578
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2033


6. GROUP BY sn.name, d.dil_name, p.name, pl.price, sp.dat, sp.quantity
7. ORDER BY d.dil_name, (count(sn.men_pers_code) * sp.quantity) DESC;
8. info (SELECT sn.name, d.dil_name, p.name, pl.price, sp.dat, (count(sn.men_pers_code) * sp.quantity)
9.       FROM products p, pricelist pl, salemap sp, saleman sn, dilers d
10.       WHERE p.prod_id = pl.prod_id AND pl.dat = sp.dat AND sp.men_pers_code = sn.men_pers_code AND sn.n_dil = d.n_dil
```

Я проверил. Не знаю, у себя в коде я таких ошибок не заметил.

Comment: "_Вот что в итоге я сделал_" - вы делаете явно что-то не то. Может я не совсем понял, что вам нужно? Пожалуйста, поясните.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что для того, чтобы реализовать эту временную переменную, мне необходимо написать под запрос, выбирающий значения из этих таблиц?

Нет, не совсем так, (под)запрос уже написан при декларации курсора.
Переменная с типом `rowtype` для этого курсора  будет объявлена и видна в теле `for-loop`:

```sql
declare 
    cursor salesinfo is -- здесь ваш запрос вместо тестовых данных
        select 'item '||rownum name, rownum*100 price, sysdate+rownum dat
        from xmlTable ('1 to 3');
begin 
    <<foreach>> for si in salesinfo loop
        -- здесь используете переменную как того требует бизнес логика
        dbms_output.put_line (si.name||chr(9)||si.price||chr(9)||si.dat);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Вывод:

```
item 1  100 2019-09-13 21:50:08
item 2  200 2019-09-14 21:50:08
item 3  300 2019-09-15 21:50:08
```

В вопросе используется явный курсор, но возможно лучше подойдёт неявный.
Более подробно об отличиях [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/729671/217579).

Answer (score 1):

Можно применить "статичное решение". Здесь тип возвращаемой записи как бы зафиксирован.

```sql
DECLARE
  l_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  TYPE t_my_record IS RECORD (
    order_id     demo_orders.order_id%TYPE, 
    quantity     demo_order_items.quantity%TYPE,
    product_name demo_product_info.product_name%TYPE);
  l_my_record t_my_record;  
BEGIN
  OPEN l_cursor FOR
  SELECT demo_orders.order_id, 
         demo_order_items.quantity,
         demo_product_info.product_name
    FROM demo_orders
         JOIN demo_order_items
           ON (demo_orders.order_id = demo_order_items.order_id)
         JOIN demo_product_info
           ON (demo_order_items.product_id = demo_product_info.product_id);
  LOOP 
    FETCH l_cursor INTO l_my_record;
    EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_my_record.order_id || ' / ' || l_my_record.quantity || ' / ' || l_my_record.product_name);
  END LOOP;  
END;
```

А можно "динамическое решение". Например, создать переменных с запасом, и вызывать нужное число `define_column` и `column_value` при определённых условиях.

```sql
DECLARE
  l_cursor  NUMBER;
  l_sql     VARCHAR2(32000);
  l_ret     NUMBER;
  l_n1      NUMBER;
  l_n2      NUMBER;
  l_c1      VARCHAR2(32000); 
BEGIN
  l_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  l_sql := 
    'SELECT demo_orders.order_id, 
            demo_order_items.quantity,
            demo_product_info.product_name
       FROM demo_orders
            JOIN demo_order_items
              ON (demo_orders.order_id = demo_order_items.order_id)
            JOIN demo_product_info
              ON (demo_order_items.product_id = demo_product_info.product_id)
      WHERE demo_orders.order_id = :p1';
  dbms_sql.parse(l_cursor, l_sql, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  dbms_sql.bind_variable(l_cursor, 'p1', 1);
  l_ret := dbms_sql.execute(l_cursor);
  dbms_sql.define_column(l_cursor, 1, l_n1);
  dbms_sql.define_column(l_cursor, 2, l_n2);
  dbms_sql.define_column(l_cursor, 3, l_c1, 100);
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_cursor) = 0;
    dbms_sql.column_value(l_cursor, 1, l_n1);
    dbms_sql.column_value(l_cursor, 2, l_n2);
    dbms_sql.column_value(l_cursor, 3, l_c1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_n1 || ' / ' || l_n2 || ' / ' || l_c1);
  END LOOP;
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_cursor);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_cursor);
    RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: Сделал правки в своём запросе. Написал весь свой код и указал то, какой лог ошибок отображает Oracle.